# $match in $lookup result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have next mongo code:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { 
            $and: [
                { UserName: { $eq: 'administrator' } }, 
                { 'Company.CompanyName': { $eq: 'test' } }
            ]                   
        } 
    },
    { 
        $lookup: { 
            from: "companies", 
            localField: "CompanyID", 
            foreignField: "CompanyID", 
            as: "Company" 
        } 
    },
])
```

The `$lookup` part of the code working great. I got next result:

[image]
[image]

But if I add `$match` to the code, it brings nothing.

I found that the problem is in the second match:  `{ 'Company.CompanyName': { $eq: 'test' } }`, but I can not realize what is wrong with it.
Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I had also tried `$unwind` on the `$lookup` result, but no luck:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { 
            $and: [
                { UserName: { $eq: 'administrator' } }, 
                { 'Company.CompanyName': { $eq: 'edt5' } }
            ] 
        } 
    },
    {   unwind: '$Company' },
    { 
        $lookup: { 
            from: 'companies', 
            localField: 'CompanyID', 
            foreignField: 'CompanyID', 
            as: 'Company' 
        } 
    },
])
```

Comment: Two points: 1: can you copy in an example of a record you think it should be  returning? Your screenshot isn't ideal because the Company data is cut off before the CompanyName field is shown 2: do you get the same problem if you run with just the $match section i.e. without the $unwind or the $lookup?

Comment: @VinceBowdren 1) Added new image with full company object.2) $match with username only runs good, but the company field become only with lookup, so how could I test it without $lookup?

Comment: You'll need to $unwind `Company` after $lookup. Add a $match stage on company field  after $unwind

Comment: @Veeram You are genius man. I broke my head nearly 5 hours... OMG. Post you answer I will accept it!!!

Comment: @chridam Mongo 3.4

Comment: @AlexBerd  chridam has answer matching your version.

Comment: @Veeram You comment was also helpfull

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With MongoDB 3.4, you can run an aggregation pipeline that uses the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline and a **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator to only return the `Company` array with elements that match the given condition. You can then wrap the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** expression with the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** operator to return a single document which in essence incorporates the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** functionality by flattening the array.

Follow this example to understand the above concept:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "UserName": "administrator" } },
    { 
        "$lookup": { 
            "from": 'companies', 
            "localField": 'CompanyID', 
            "foreignField": 'CompanyID', 
            "as": 'Company' 
        } 
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "Company": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$Company",
                            "as": "comp",
                            "cond": {
                                "$eq": [ "$$comp.CompanyName", "edt5" ]
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: You beat me to it. You may need to move the `$addFields` stage after lookup and remove the `CompanyName` part from `$match` .  I think the `CompanyName` is the field in the looked up collection

Comment: @Veeram You are right, thanks for noticing. I've updated the answer to include the OP's original desired query. Cheers!

Answer (score 36):

**Below answer is for mongoDB 3.6 or later.**

Given that:

- You have a collection `users` with a field `CompanyID` and a collection of `companies` with a field `CompanyID`
- you want to lookup `Companies` on `Users` by matching `CompanyID`, where additionally:

  - each User must match condition: `User.UserName` equals `administrator`
  - each `Company` on `User` must match condition: `CompanyName` equals `edt5`

The following query will work for you:

```
  db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: { UserName: 'administrator' } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'companies',
        as: 'Company',
        let: { CompanyID: '$CompanyID' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ['$CompanyID', '$$CompanyID'] },
                  { $eq: ['$CompanyName', 'edt5'] },
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  ])
```

**Explanation:**
This is the way to perform left join queries with conditions more complex than simple foreign / local field equality match.

Instead of using `localField` and `foreignField`, you use:

- `let` option where you can map local fields to variables,
- `pipeline` option where you can specify aggregation `Array`.

In `pipeline` you can use `$match` filter, with `$expr`, where you can reuse variables defined earlier in `let`.

[More info on $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

[Nice tutorial](https://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-lookup-expr)

Comment: Regarding `{ $eq: ['$CompanyID', '$$CompanyID'] },`. The left side is the field in `companies`

Comment: this provides more results than it should be

Comment: Thank for all the explanation. This answers is indeed the best way to do it with latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

here is code for fitering array inside lookup.

```
 const userId = req.userData.userId;
const limit = parseInt(req.params.limit);
const page = parseInt(req.params.page);

Collection.aggregate([
 { $match: {} },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } },
  { $skip: limit * page },
  { $limit: limit },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: Preference.collection.name,
      let: { keywordId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$keyword", "$$keywordId"] },
                {
                  $eq: ["$user", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "keywordData",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: "$_id",
      count: 1,
      for: 1,
      against: 1,
      created_at: 1,
      updated_at: 1,
      keyword: 1,
      selected: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [{ $size: "$keywordData" }, 0],
          },
          then: false,
          else: true,
        },
      },
    },
  }])
```